# What does this warning triangle means?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I'm creating a .NET Core 2.0 Web Application in Visual Studio 2017,
In some dependencies, I have these yellow triangles. There's no any info about it. What does it mean?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It means the assembly (dll) can't be found in the location it should be. Usually this is because an assembly didn't compile, or you performed a clean and an external reference was removed, or other reasons depending on the project structure.

In this case you need to check you have the correct dot.NET Entity Framework Core (ensure it is **core**, so v6 and up since normal 'Entity Framework' is not core compatible) installed.

Oh, and the warning triangles on the items above are just carried up from the main issue marked deeper down the tree.

Hope this helps

Comment: It is problem with my computer, there are no triangles when starting project on another computer

Comment: HI. Anything is possible. Unfortunately, it is never easy to debug a project remotely. I would suggest it is only a corrupt installation of the framework required for the project if anything. You can check this by re-installing the core entity framework from nuget package manager [entity framework core 2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/). Sometimes you need to restore ALL of the packages, and this can be forced by deleting the project Lib folder using Windows Explorer. The Lib folder usually resides under the wwwRoot folder in the project folder.

Comment: Once you have deleted the Lib folder, just perform a rebuild all on the solution, and all packages will be restored before building (as long as you haven't switched the option off in your VS 2017 options!) ;)